# Py: random int distribution of numbers over [list] with exact sum

Tags: python, random, while-loop

I'll be as concice as I can be.

I have a number generated by other means:

`topic_interest_0 = 50 # this number is generated elsewhere`

I have a list with a number of items, in this case 7:

`topic_interest_literature =      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

I need to distribute topic_interest_0 randomly over topic_interest_literature but where the sum of all items in topic_interest_literature is topic_interest_0 and no item is larger than 10.

I have tried a while loop:

```
while topic_interest_0 > 0:
            if topic_interest_0 >= 10:
                topic_interest_literature[0] = random.randint(0, 10)
            else:
                topic_interest_literature[0] = random.randint(0, topic_interest_0)
                
            topic_interest_0 -= topic_interest_literature[0]
```

And run this for every item in topic_interest_literature 0 to 6. But this is tedious since I have multiple other such lists to go through, plus it will always leave me with either a surplus or a deficit on the last possible random.

Comment: Let me point out that doing `50 // 7` solves the problem.  Why introduce randomness?

Comment: @TimRoberts Because the resulting list will be used elsewhere where this randomness is desired.

Comment: Must the values in `topic_interest_literature` be uniformly distributed, or may they be random without any specific distribution?

Comment: @MichaelRuth they 'must' be randomly distributed or at least pseudo-randomly. This is part of a game where these values form parameters the player isn't sure off beforehand. That is why randomness, seed or another form of pseudo-random distribution is highly desired.

Comment: I understand the randomness requirement. My question is: does this require a specific distribution?

Comment: @MichaelRuth ah, so. No, the distribution can be random.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is sampling uniformly from a discrete/integer simplex. You'd probably get better answers asking on another SE such as Math; although the actual implementation is a CS question, the algorithm is more Math-y.

Some googling got me this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/uniform-sampling-from-a-simplex

That answer gives an algorithm for the continuous case. Adapting it to the discrete case,

```
from random import choices
samples = choices(range(topic_interest_0+1), k = topic_interest_0-1)
samples.extend([0, topic_interest_0])
samples.sort()
topic_interest_literature = [b-a for a,b in zip(samples[0:-1], samples[1:])]
```

This doesn't guarantee that some won't be more than 10, however. I'm not sure what the optimum way of fixing this is, but if you're not too concerned about uniformity, you could take every entry that exceeds 10, and distribute the excess to the smaller numbers. You could also distribute out the average to each bucket, then pair buckets up and add a random number to one of the buckets in the pair, and subtract from the other.

Comment: This is an interesting solution and it does a good job of distributing an integer over a number of samples. However, this also grows topic_interest_literature by 1 iteration.

samples0.extend([topic_interest_0]) fixes this. As you said, this will create values above 10 as well.